# PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I need to query for each minute the total count of rows up to that minute.

The best I could achieve so far doesn't do the trick. It returns count per minute, not the total count up to each minute:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count
     , EXTRACT(hour from "when") AS hour
     , EXTRACT(minute from "when") AS minute
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY hour, minute
```

Comment: Do you want a SUM or a COUNT of the number of columns? The example query isn't clear.

Comment: What do you mean by sum of rows?

Comment: Total count. Sorry I will fix the example

Comment: Do you want count rows produced by this query?

Comment: Yes. count the rows - but a count for each minute

Comment: we are all having a problem with "count of rows sliced to minute" vs "(it returns count per each minute_" vs "but a count for each minute".  I would suggest you rethink and edit your question to clarify these inconsistencies.

Comment: some of the description sounds like a 'running total' if that helps.

Comment: IMO you should do something like this: `SELECT MAX(rnum) AS count
     , EXTRACT(hour from "when") AS hour
     , EXTRACT(minute from "when") AS minute FROM (SELECT mytable.*, rnum FROM mytable ORDER BY "When") GROUP BY hour, minute`, where rnum should be row number (but I don't remember how to achieve this).

Comment: @Michael Durrant - Ok I rephrased the question

Comment: Thx.  I updated the title to reflect it. :)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

### Return only minutes with activity

#### Shortest

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       date_trunc('minute', "when") AS minute
     , count(*) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('minute', "when")) AS running_ct
FROM   mytable
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), it returns exactly what you need.

Don't include `id` in the query, since you want to `GROUP BY` minute slices.

`count()` is typically used as plain [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html). Appending an `OVER` clause makes it a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). Omit `PARTITION BY` in the window definition - you want a running count *over all rows*. By default, that counts from the first row to the last peer of the current row as defined by `ORDER BY`. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is the
> same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. With `ORDER BY`,
> this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition start up
> through the current row's last `ORDER BY` peer.

And that happens to be *exactly* what you need.

Use `count(*)` rather than `count(id)`. It better fits your question ("count of rows"). It is generally slightly *faster* than `count(id)`. And, while we might assume that `id` is `NOT NULL`, it has not been specified in the question, so `count(id)` is *wrong*, strictly speaking, because NULL values are not counted with `count(id)`.

You can't `GROUP BY` minute slices at the same query level. Aggregate functions are applied *before* window functions, the window function `count(*)` would only see 1 row per minute this way.
You can, however, `SELECT DISTINCT`, because `DISTINCT` is applied *after* window functions.

`ORDER BY 1` is just shorthand for `ORDER BY date_trunc('minute', "when")` here.
`1` is a positional reference reference to the 1st expression in the `SELECT` list.

Use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) if you need to format the result. Like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       to_char(date_trunc('minute', "when"), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS minute
     , count(*) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('minute', "when")) AS running_ct
FROM   mytable
ORDER  BY date_trunc('minute', "when");
```

#### Fastest

```sql
SELECT minute, sum(minute_ct) OVER (ORDER BY minute) AS running_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('minute', "when") AS minute
        , count(*) AS minute_ct
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Much like the above, but:

I use a subquery to aggregate and count rows per minute. This way we get 1 row per minute without `DISTINCT` in the outer `SELECT`.

Use `sum()` as window aggregate function now to add up the counts from the subquery.

I found this to be substantially faster with many rows per minute.

### Include minutes without activity

#### Shortest

[@GabiMe asked in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#comment10143564_8194088) how to get eone row for **every** `minute` in the time frame, including those where no event occured (no row in base table):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       minute, count(c.minute) OVER (ORDER BY minute) AS running_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('minute', min("when"))
                        ,                      max("when")
                        , interval '1 min')
   FROM   tbl
   ) m(minute)
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT date_trunc('minute', "when") FROM tbl) c(minute) USING (minute)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Generate a row for every minute in the time frame between the first and the last event with [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) - here directly based on aggregated values from the subquery.

`LEFT JOIN` to all timestamps truncated to the minute and count. `NULL` values (where no row exists) do not add to the running count.

#### Fastest

With CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT date_trunc('minute', "when") AS minute, count(*) AS minute_ct
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) 
SELECT m.minute
     , COALESCE(sum(cte.minute_ct) OVER (ORDER BY m.minute), 0) AS running_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(min(minute), max(minute), interval '1 min')
   FROM   cte
   ) m(minute)
LEFT   JOIN cte USING (minute)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Again, aggregate and count rows per minute in the first step, it omits the need for later `DISTINCT`.

Different from `count()`, `sum()` can return `NULL`. Default to `0` with `COALESCE`.

With many rows and an **index on `"when"`** this version with a subquery was fastest among a couple of variants I tested with Postgres 9.1 - 9.4:

```sql
SELECT m.minute
     , COALESCE(sum(c.minute_ct) OVER (ORDER BY m.minute), 0) AS running_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('minute', min("when"))
                        ,                      max("when")
                        , interval '1 min')
   FROM   tbl
   ) m(minute)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('minute', "when") AS minute
        , count(*) AS minute_ct
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (minute)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Comment: I mean, the even if running_ct==0 it would be shown in the results (i.e. return row set of all the minutes, not only the ones with activity in it)

Comment: @bugspy.net: this is a whole new question. I added another answer to my answer.

Comment: @bugspy.net: [But you can.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) ;)

Comment: Done! I awarded you 100 pts as a bounty

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter amazing answer! This was very helpful for me thanks a lot