# Get difference of another field between first and last timestamps of grouping

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a very large table called `sensor_values` with the columns `timestamp`, `value`, `sensor_id` and another table called `sensors` which has say `sensor_id`, `name`.

I often perform a pivot query to get summed data grouped by day like this:

```
SELECT MIN(to_char(s1.timestamp::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ')) AS time,
      SUM(CASE WHEN s1.sensor_id = 572 THEN s1.value ELSE 0.0 END) AS "Nickname1",
      SUM(CASE WHEN s1.sensor_id = 542 THEN s1.value ELSE 0.0 END) AS "Nickname2",
      SUM(CASE WHEN s1.sensor_id = 571 THEN s1.value ELSE 0.0 END) AS "Nickname3"
FROM sensor_values s1
WHERE s1.timestamp::timestamptz >= '2013-10-14T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz
AND s1.timestamp::timestamptz <= '2013-10-18T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz
AND s1.sensor_id IN (572, 542, 571, 540, 541, 573)
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', s1.timestamp) ORDER BY 1 ;
```

This works OK if a bit slow. However, is it possible to write a similar query that
instead of summing the groups it gets the difference between the latest and earliest timestamps in each grouping, i.e. day in this case?

This is because I have some sensor data that is ever increasing (electrical kwh meter)
and would like to know the consumption in a particular time frame.

Comment: No explanation for `sensor_values_cleaned`? You really need to provide your table definitions with a question like this (`\d tbl` in psql), and a test case to work with - ideally as [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). And, as *always*, your version of Postgres.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the sql. sensor_values_cleaned was a identical table to sensor_values but with modified values. It's not important for the question so have removed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1: Release the handbrakes

> ... if a bit slow

```
SELECT to_char(MIN(ts)::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ') AS min_time
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 572 THEN value ELSE 0.0 END) AS nickname1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 542 THEN value ELSE 0.0 END) AS nickname2
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN sensor_id = 571 THEN value ELSE 0.0 END) AS nickname3
FROM   sensor_values
-- LEFT JOIN sensor_values_cleaned s2 USING (sensor_id, ts)
WHERE  ts >= '2013-10-14T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz::timestamp
AND    ts <  '2013-10-18T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz::timestamp
AND    sensor_id IN (572, 542, 571, 540, 541, 573)
GROUP  BY ts::date AS day
ORDER  BY 1;
```

#### Major points

- Replace [**reserved words**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (in standard SQL) in your identifiers.
  `timestamp` -> `ts`
  `time` -> `min_time`
- Since the join is on identical column names you can use the simpler [**`USING` clause**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) in the join condition: `USING (sensor_id, ts)`
  However, since the second table `sensor_values_cleaned` is 100% irrelevant to this query, I removed it entirely.
- As @joop already advised, switch `min()` and `to_char()` in your first out put column. This way, Postgres can determine the minimum from the **original column value**, which is generally faster and may be able to utilize an index. In this specific case, **ordering by `date`** is also cheaper than ordering by a `text`, which would also have to consider collation rules.
- A similar consideration applies to your `WHERE` condition:
  <strike>WHERE  ts::timestamptz >= '2013-10-14T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz</strike>

  ```
  WHERE  ts >= '2013-10-14T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz::timestamp
  ```

  The second one is [**sargable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and can utilize a plain index on `ts` - to great effect on performance in big tables!
- Using `ts::date` instead of `date_trunc('day', ts)`. Simpler, faster, same result.
- Most probably your second WHERE condition is slightly incorrect. Generally, you would **exclude the upper border**:


  ```
  AND    ts <=  '2013-10-18T00:00:00+00:00' ...
  ```

  ```
  AND    ts <   '2013-10-18T00:00:00+00:00' ...
  ```
- When mixing `timestamp` and `timestamptz` one needs to be aware of the effects. For instance, your `WHERE` condition doesn't cut at 00:00 local time (except if local time coincides with UTC). Details here:
  [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

### Step 2: Your request

> ...the difference between the latest and earliest timestamps in each grouping

And by that I suppose you mean:
...the difference between ***the value of***  the latest and earliest timestamps ...
Otherwise it would be much simpler.

Use [**window functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) for that, in particular `first_value()` and `last_value()`. Careful with the combination, you want a [non-standard window frame](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for last_value() in this case. Compare:
[PostgreSQL aggregate or window function to return just the last value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320569/postgresql-aggregate-or-window-function-to-return-just-the-last-value/8320588#8320588)

I combine this with [**`DISTINCT ON`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564), which is more convenient in this case than `GROUP BY` (which would need another subquery level):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ts::date, sensor_id)
       ts::date AS day
      ,to_char((min(ts)  OVER (PARTITION BY ts::date))::timestamptz
              ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ') AS min_time
      ,sensor_id
      ,last_value(value)    OVER (PARTITION BY ts::date, sensor_id ORDER BY ts
                     RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       - first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ts::date, sensor_id ORDER BY ts)
                                                                   AS val_range
FROM   sensor_values
WHERE  ts >= '2013-10-14T00:00:00+0'::timestamptz::timestamp
AND    ts <  '2013-10-18T00:00:00+0'::timestamptz::timestamp
AND    sensor_id IN (540, 541, 542, 571, 572, 573)
ORDER  BY ts::date, sensor_id;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07461/1)

### Step 3: Pivot table

Building on the query above I use [**`crosstab()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905) from the additional module `tablefunc`:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$SELECT DISTINCT ON (1,3)
            ts::date AS day
           ,to_char((min(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY ts::date))::timestamptz,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ') AS min_time
           ,sensor_id
           ,last_value(value)    OVER (PARTITION BY ts::date, sensor_id ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
            - first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY ts::date, sensor_id ORDER BY ts) AS val_range
     FROM   sensor_values
     WHERE  ts >= '2013-10-14T00:00:00+0'::timestamptz::timestamp
     AND    ts <  '2013-10-18T00:00:00+0'::timestamptz::timestamp
     AND    sensor_id IN (540, 541, 542, 571, 572, 573)
     ORDER  BY 1, 3$$

   ,$$VALUES (540), (541), (542), (571), (572), (573)$$
   )
AS ct (day date, min_time text, s540 numeric, s541 numeric, s542 numeric, s571 numeric, s572 numeric, s573 numeric);
```

Returns (and *much* faster than before):

```
    day     |         min_time         | s540  | s541  | s542  | s571  | s572  | s573
------------+--------------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
 2013-10-14 | 2013-10-14 03:00:00 CEST | 18.82 | 18.98 | 19.97 | 19.47 | 17.56 | 21.27
 2013-10-15 | 2013-10-15 00:15:00 CEST | 22.59 | 24.20 | 22.90 | 21.27 | 22.75 | 22.23
 2013-10-16 | 2013-10-16 00:16:00 CEST | 23.74 | 22.52 | 22.23 | 23.22 | 23.03 | 22.98
 2013-10-17 | 2013-10-17 00:17:00 CEST | 21.68 | 24.54 | 21.15 | 23.58 | 23.04 | 21.94
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
SELECT MIN(to_char(s1.timestamp::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ')) AS time,
```

by:

```
SELECT to_char(MIN(s1.timestamp)::timestamptz, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZ') AS zztime,
```

or even:

```
SELECT MIN(s1.timestamp) AS zztime,
```

*since the datetimestampformat you specify is more or less the default*

This will avoid the min-selection on a computed expression.

BTW: `timestamp` and `time` are both reserved words (type names) in (postgres) SQL. Try to avoid using them as identifiers.

Comment: In this case I actually want the minimum time in each group.

Comment: In that case you don't need to cast to character. Dates are orderable.

Comment: `to_char()` is not redundant here, since it outputs the time zone *name* (as opposed to tz offset or tz abbreviation).

Comment: Makes perfect sense to want the **minimum** of the zone _name_ ... (given ties on the datetime part)