# How to return rows from three tables at once?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

How do merge these three  queries into one?

1.

```
SELECT "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", "TrainerScores"."fellow_uid", MIN("TrainerScores"."score") AS "score"
FROM "TrainerScores"
INNER JOIN "Skills" ON "TrainerScores"."skill_id" = "Skills"."id"
WHERE "TrainerScores"."fellow_uid" = 'google:105697533513134511631'
AND DATE("TrainerScores"."created_at") BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
GROUP BY "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", "TrainerScores"."fellow_uid"
```

2.

```
Select "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", MIN("PeerScores"."score") AS "score"
FROM "PeerScores"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Skills" ON "PeerScores"."skill_id" = "Skills"."id"
WHERE "PeerScores"."evaluatee_uid" = 'google:105697533513134511631'
AND DATE("PeerScores"."created_at") BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
GROUP BY "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id"
```

3.

```
Select "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", MIN("SelfScores"."score") AS "score"
FROM "SelfScores"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Skills" ON "SelfScores"."skill_id" = "Skills"."id"
WHERE "SelfScores"."fellow_uid" = 'google:105697533513134511631'
AND DATE("SelfScores"."created_at") BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
GROUP BY "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id"
```

I want to use this as a report and I do not want to call each one of the queries any time I want to get the data.

Comment: @AyoolaSolmon 
I'm not sure if it is possible to join these three queries, but with sequelize is possible to obtain results in all three in the same function, using callback.

Comment: @LucasCosta how do you think i can go about this with sequelize

Comment: Why don't you want to just use the three queries? What problem do you expect to solve by combining them?

Comment: @CraigRinger I want to represent the minimum score of each table as an horizontal bar chart and i want to use get the data once and not like three times

Comment: Simply UNION ALL? Either between the three scores tables before LEFT JOIN. Or one big (double) UNION ALL.

Comment: how @jarlh do i go about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, use `UNION ALL` like [@jarlh already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33413757/939860).
Details in the manual in the chapter [**"Combining Queries"**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html).

But there is a ***lot more***. My educated guess, you really want this:

```sql
WITH vals AS (SELECT timestamp '2015-10-01 00:00' AS ts_low  -- incl. lower bound
                   , timestamp '2015-10-31 00:00' AS ts_hi   -- excl. upper bound
                   , text 'google:105697533513134511631' AS uid)
SELECT s.name, sub.*
FROM  (
   SELECT skill_id AS id, min(score) AS score, 'T' AS source
   FROM   "TrainerScores", vals v
   WHERE  fellow_uid =  v.uid
   AND    created_at >= v.ts_low
   AND    created_at <  v.ts_hi
   GROUP  BY 1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT skill_id, min(score), 'P'
   FROM   "PeerScores", vals v
   WHERE  evaluatee_uid = v.uid
   AND    created_at >= v.ts_low
   AND    created_at <  v.ts_hi
   GROUP  BY 1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT skill_id, min(score), 'S'
   FROM   "SelfScores", vals v
   WHERE  fellow_uid =  v.uid
   AND    created_at >= v.ts_low
   AND    created_at <  v.ts_hi
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
JOIN   "Skills" s USING (id);
```

#### Major points

- First I trimmed the noise from your syntax (probably produced by your ORM) to make it human-readable: remove redundant double-quotes, add table aliases, trim noise words ...
- Your use of `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` was broken, since you filter on columns of the left table, which counteracts the `LEFT JOIN`. Replace with `[INNER] JOIN`.
- Use [**sargable**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable) expressions in the `WHERE` clause or your query can't use plain indexes and will be very slow for big tables. Related:

  - [Get difference of another field between first and last timestamps of grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565421/get-difference-of-another-field-between-first-and-last-timestamps-of-grouping/20574117#20574117)
- Provide your parameters ***once*** in a CTE (`WITH` clause) - which is not needed in a prepared statement where you pass `uid`, `ts_low` and `ts_hi` as parameters instead.
- I removed `"TrainerScores"."fellow_uid"` from the output in your first query to simplify the query. That's just your input parameter anyway.
- You can aggregate your respective main tables ***before*** you join to `"Skills"` *once*.
- I added a column `source` to signify the source of each row.

Aside: It seems like you want to match the whole of October 2015, but then you exclude Oct. 31. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Thanks @Erwin you saved my day

Comment: One last thing @Erwin Brandstetter, i want the timestamp to be inclusive of the ts_hi

Comment: @AyoolaSolomon: Are you sure of this? `created_at <  timestamp '2015-10-31 00:00'` does the same (smarter) as `date(created_at) <=  date '2015-10-30'`. (I had missed Oct. 31 in my initial answer and fixed that now!) When dealing with timestamps you typically want to *include* the lower and *exclude* the upper bound. Dates are different because there are no fractional digits.

Comment: I am sure about that because i want to be able to include the date i am creating the data when am fetching it from the database... Thanks

Comment: In response to your answer ... I am just using that as an example.. Hope you understand

Comment: @AyoolaSolomon: To *include* a certain date, use `created_at < (date '2015-10-30' + 1)` - which is effectively the same as `created_at < timestamp '2015-10-31 00:00'`.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Bandstetter

Answer (score 3):

Alternative 1, simply a huge `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", "TrainerScores"."fellow_uid", MIN("TrainerScores"."score") AS "score"
FROM "TrainerScores"
INNER JOIN "Skills" ON "TrainerScores"."skill_id" = "Skills"."id"
WHERE "TrainerScores"."fellow_uid" = 'google:105697533513134511631'
AND DATE("TrainerScores"."created_at") BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
GROUP BY "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", "TrainerScores"."fellow_uid"

UNION ALL

Select "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", NULL, MIN("PeerScores"."score") AS "score"
FROM "PeerScores"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Skills" ON "PeerScores"."skill_id" = "Skills"."id"
WHERE "PeerScores"."evaluatee_uid" = 'google:105697533513134511631'
AND DATE("PeerScores"."created_at") BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
GROUP BY "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id"

UNION ALL

Select "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id", NULL, MIN("SelfScores"."score") AS "score"
FROM "SelfScores"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Skills" ON "SelfScores"."skill_id" = "Skills"."id"
WHERE "SelfScores"."fellow_uid" = 'google:105697533513134511631'
AND DATE("SelfScores"."created_at") BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
GROUP BY "Skills"."name", "Skills"."id"
```

Comment: @jarih The Union will defeat the purpose. I want to be able to seperate each of the data from the respective tables.

Comment: @AyoolaSolomon, what about adding different literal values to each select? select 'q1', ... UNION ALL select 'q2', ... UNION ALL select 'q3'? Then you'll know from which select every row origins.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution that does exactly what you want, but it works. Using [raw](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/) query you can run and get the results of multiple queries, something like this:

```
var sequelize = require('./libs/pg_db_connect');

var query = "SELECT Skills.name, Skills.id, TrainerScores.fellow_uid, MIN(TrainerScores.score) AS score
FROM TrainerScores
INNER JOIN Skills ON TrainerScores.skill_id = Skills.id
WHERE TrainerScores.fellow_uid = 'google:105697533513134511631' AND DATE(TrainerScores.created_at) BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
GROUP BY Skills.name, Skills.id, TrainerScores.fellow_uid";


sequelize.query(query, {
   type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
}).success(function (query1) {
   done = _.after(query1.length, function () {
      callback(query1)
   })

   query = "Select Skills.name, Skills.id, MIN(PeerScores.score) AS score
        FROM PeerScores
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Skills ON PeerScores.skill_id = Skills.id
        WHERE PeerScores.evaluatee_uid = 'google:105697533513134511631' AND DATE(PeerScores.created_at) BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
        GROUP BY Skills.name, Skills.id";

   sequelize.query(query, {
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
   }).success(function (query2) {

      query = "Select Skills.name, Skills.id, MIN(SelfScores.score) AS score
        FROM SelfScores
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Skills ON SelfScores.skill_id = Skills.id
        WHERE SelfScores.fellow_uid = 'google:105697533513134511631' AND DATE(SelfScores.created_at) BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-30'
        GROUP BY Skills.name, Skills.id";

      sequelize.query(query, {
         type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
      }).success(function (query3) {
         console.log(query1); // show the returns of query 1
         console.log(query2); // show the returns of query 2
         console.log(query3); // show the returns of query 3
      });
```

The results of `success` function of `sequelize.query` can be storage in the json variable too.

Comment: I could go wit this... But is there a way i can have a cleaner query?