# Longest Prefix Match

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, longest-prefix

What's the best way to get accurate and fast queries in PostgreSQL for a longest prefix match?

Is it:

```
A.) select * from table where column in (subselect) ;

B.) select * from table where strpos(column,column2) = 1
    order by length(column2) desc limit 1 ;

C.) select * from table where column ~ column2
    order by length(column2) desc limit 1
```

I'm planning to use in an update. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually want to compare each column with another column in the same row? Or rather find the longest match for string or list of strings in the whole table? Please **edit the question** to clarify.

Comment: I did not quite pick up on what you said but yes you are correct, I would like to find the longest match for string/strings from a separate table. Can you help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know of a function doing this out of the box in PostgreSQL.
A [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) would be the key element for a rather elegant solution (available in PostgreSQL 8.4 or later).

I am assuming a table `filter` to hold the filter strings:

```
CREATE TABLE filter (f_id int, string text);
```

And a table `tbl` to be search for the longest match:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(t_id int, col text);
```

#### Query

```
WITH RECURSIVE
     f AS (SELECT f_id, string, length(string) AS flen FROM filter)
    ,t AS (SELECT t_id, col, length(col) AS tlen FROM tbl)
    ,x AS (
    SELECT t.t_id, f.f_id, t.col, f.string
          ,2 AS match, LEAST(flen, tlen) AS len
    FROM   t
    JOIN   f ON left(t.col, 1) = left(f.string, 1)

    UNION ALL
    SELECT t_id, f_id, col, string, match + 1, len
    FROM   x
    WHERE  left(col, match) = left(string, match)
    AND    match <= len
    )
SELECT DISTINCT
       f_id
      ,string
      ,first_value(col) OVER w AS col
      ,first_value(t_id) OVER w AS t_id
      ,(first_value(match) OVER w -1) AS longest_match
FROM   x
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY f_id ORDER BY match DESC)
ORDER  BY 2,1,3,4;
```

[Detailed explanation how the final SELECT works in this related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)
[Working demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1b5d6/1)

You did not define which match to pick from a set of equally long matches. I am picking one arbitrary winner from ties.

> I'm planning to use in an update.

PostgreSQL 9.1 introduced [data modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), so you can use this in an `UPDATE` statement directly.