# Aggregate highest prices per client of salesmen

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders;

 client_id | order_id | salesman_id | price
-----------+----------+-------------+-------
         1 |      167 |           1 |    65
         1 |      367 |           1 |    27
         2 |      401 |           1 |    29
         2 |      490 |           2 |    48
         3 |      199 |           1 |    68
         3 |      336 |           2 |    22
         3 |      443 |           1 |    84
         3 |      460 |           2 |    92
```

I want to find the an array of order_ids for each of the highest priced sales for each unique salesman and client pair. In this case I want the resulting table:

```
 salesman_id |   order_id
-------------+----------------
           1 | {167, 401, 443}
           2 | {490, 460}
```

So far I have an outline for a query:

```
SELECT salesman_id, max_client_salesman(order_id)
FROM orders
GROUP BY salesman_id;
```

However I'm having trouble writing the [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/xaggr.html) max_client_salesman.

The documentation online for aggregate functions and arrays in postgres is very minimal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How would you deal with two equally highest prices for one `(salesman_id, client_id)`? Pick one randomly? Pick both? Also, as *always*, declare the version of PostgreSQL in use.

Comment: If there are matching prices then it doesn't really matter which one is chosen. I'm working on postgres 9.0 (unfortunately). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Standard SQL

I would combine the [window function `last_value()` or `firstvalue()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) with `DISTINCT` to the get the orders with the highest price per `(salesman_id, client_id)` efficiently and then aggregate this into the array you are looking for with the simple [aggregate function `array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).

```
SELECT salesman_id
      ,array_agg(max_order_id) AS most_expensive_orders_per_client
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT
          salesman_id, client_id
         ,last_value(order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY salesman_id, client_id
                                     ORDER BY price
                                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                     AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS max_order_id
   FROM   orders
   ) x
GROUP  BY salesman_id
ORDER  BY salesman_id;
```

Returns:

```
 salesman_id |  most_expensive_orders_per_client
-------------+------------------------------------
           1 | {167, 401, 443}
           2 | {490, 460}
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/68617/1)

If there are multiple highest prices per `(salesman_id, client_id)`, this query pick only *one* `order_id` arbitrarily - for lack of definition.

For this solution it is essential to understand that window functions are applied before `DISTINCT`. How you to combine `DISTINCT` with a window function:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

For an explanation on `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` refer to [this closely related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/postgresql-view-with-max-min-with-id/9800#9800).

#### Simper with non-standard [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

PostgreSQL implements, as extension to the SQL standard, `DISTINCT ON`. With it you can very effectively select rows unique according to a defined set of columns.
It won't get simpler or faster than this:

```
SELECT salesman_id
      ,array_agg(order_id) AS most_expensive_orders_per_client
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, client_id)
          salesman_id, order_id
   FROM   orders
   ORDER  BY salesman_id, client_id, price DESC
   ) x
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/68617/1)

I also use positional parameters for shorter syntax. Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: The first answer works. I didn't understand window functions until now. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @wesdotcool: Nice. :) BTW, both answers should work and the 2nd should be faster. I added an SQLfiddle to demonstrate (and to play with).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the Postgres function `array_agg` in combination with `row_number()`  However, your description of the query does not make sense to me.

The following gets clients and salesmen and the list of orders for the highest priced order by salesman:

```
select client_id, salesman_id, array_agg(order_id)
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by salesman_id order by price desc) as sseqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by price desc) as cseqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where sseqnum = 1
group by salesman_id, client_id
```

I don't know what you mean by "highest priced sales for each salesman and client".  Perhaps you want:

```
where sseqnum = 1 or cseqnum = 1
```

Comment: I accidentally included an extra column in the example output. By "highest priced sales for each salesman and client" I mean that I want an order_id to be included in an array if it was the highest price interaction between a client and a salesman. So if Bob sells Jim a $50 and $40 item, I just want the order_id of the $50 item.