# Resample on time series data

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, aggregate-functions

I have a table with time series column in the millisecond, I want to resample the time series and apply mean on the group. How can I implement it in Postgres?

"Resample" means aggregate all time stamps within one second or one minute. All rows within one second or one minute form a group.

table structure

```
date    x    y    z
```

Comment: What do you mean by resample? How do you define a group?

Comment: Please supply a table definition, test data and the query you tried (even if it's not working). Also, your version of Postgres.

Comment: What is your postgres version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [**`date_trunc()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to truncate timestamps to a given unit of time, and `GROUP BY` that expression:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', date) AS date_truncated_to_minute
     , avg(x) AS avg_x
     , avg(y) AS avg_y
     , avg(z) AS avg_z
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Assuming your misleadingly named `date` column is actually of type `timestamp` or `timestamptz`.

Related answer with more details and links:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)