# Postgres LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, left-join, date-range

I need to left join two tables with a where condition:

Table `time_table`

```
id     rid        start_date                end_date
1       2     2017-07-01 00:00:00     2018-11-01 00:00:00
2       5     2017-01-01 00:00:00     2017-06-01 00:00:00
3       2     2018-07-01 00:00:00     2020-11-01 00:00:00
```

Table `record_table`

```
id      name                 date
1      record1       2017-10-01 00:00:00
2      record2       2017-02-01 00:00:00
3      record3       2017-10-01 00:00:00
```

I need to get all those records which are present under given date range. In the above example, I need those records that lie under range for `rid = 2` only. Hence the output for the above query needs to be:

```
1      record1       2017-10-01 00:00:00    
3      record3       2017-10-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post some sample code and output, and tell us what isn't working for you. Also, check this link out: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: are you using postgresql or mysql?

Comment: Your output example does not require an outer join as in the question title. It is an inner join.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: A `LEFT JOIN` makes sense to show the row(s) (or selected columns) from `time_table` matching `rid = 2`, even if no row in `record_table` overlaps with the time range. Else, if the user gets an empty result (no row), and (s)he can't tell whether there's no match in `time_table` (no `rid = 2`) or in `record_table`. Of course, it would make sense to include `start_date` and `end_date` in the result, or you just get a row of NULL values for the latter case - which would still be significant.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Although it is possible to make the query complete the posted output example does not give a hint on that. The OP mentions `left join` but it could just be some misunderstanding. Without a clarification from him I tend to put more weight on the desired output. My comment above is a call for elucidation and I should have made it clear. But congratulations for your always detailed answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> left join two tables with a where condition

It's typically *wrong* to use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` and then filter with a `WHERE` condition on the right table, thereby voiding the special feature of a `LEFT JOIN` to include all rows from the left table *unconditionally*. Detailed explanation:

- [Explain JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN and WHERE condition performance suggestion in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de/24876797#24876797)

Put conditions supposed to filter all rows into the `WHERE` clause (`rid = 2`), but move conditions on `record_table` to the join clause:

```
SELECT t.start_date, t.end_date  -- adding those
     , r.id, r.name, r.date 
FROM   time_table t
LEFT   JOIN record_table r ON r.date >= t.start_date
                          AND r.date <  t.end_date
WHERE  t.rid = 2;
```

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465260/postgres-left-join-with-where-condition#comment68198820_40465260), it makes sense to include columns from `time_table` in the result, but that's my optional addition.

You also need to be clear about **lower and upper bounds**. The general convention is to *include* the lower and *exclude* the upper bound in time (`timestamp`) ranges. Hence my use of `>=` and `<` above.

Related:

- [SQL query on a time series to calculate the average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679036/sql-query-on-a-time-series-to-calculate-the-average/28713972#28713972)
- [Selecting an average of records grouped by 5 minute periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428951/selecting-an-average-of-records-grouped-by-5-minute-periods/20429727#20429727)

Performance should be *no problem at all* with the right indexes.
You need an index (or PK) on `time_table(rid)` and another on `record_table(date)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but if you are saying you want the dates where the record_table date is between the dates in the time_table, then this would do the job:

```
select
  rt.id, rt.name, rt.date
from
  time_table tt
  join record_table rt on
    rt.date between tt.start_date and tt.end_date
where
  tt.rid = 2
```

That said, this will be horribly inefficient for large datasets.  If your data is relatively small (< 10k records in each table, post-filters), then it probably won't matter much, but if you would need to scale this concept, it would warrant knowing more about your data -- for example, do the dates, always round to the first of each month?

Again, from your example, I wasn't sure if this is what you meant by "get all those records which are present under given date range."

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT time_tbl.name,record_tbl.date 
FROM dbo.time_table AS time_tbl
     INNER JOIN record_table AS record_tbl
           ON time_tbl.id=record_tbl.id
WHERE(time_tbl.rid=2)
```

Comment: This is incorrect in almost every aspect. Wrong JOIN, incorrect condition, wrong result columns. That can happen, but most importantly: no explanation at all.