# Ensuring no dupe ids in query return

Tags: sql, postgresql

So for the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE activity (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    start_date date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE account (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE contact (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    account_id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE activity_contact (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    contact_id integer NOT NULL,
    activity_id integer NOT NULL
);

insert into activity(id, start_date)
values
(1, '2021-11-03'),
(2, '2021-10-03'),
(3, '2021-11-02');

insert into account(id, name)
values
(1, 'Test Account');

insert into contact(id, account_id, name)
values
(1, 1, 'John'),
(2, 1, 'Kevin');

insert into activity_contact(id, contact_id, activity_id)
values
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 2, 2),
(4, 1, 3);
```

You can see that there are 3 activities and each contact has two. What i am searching for is the number of activities per account in the previous two months. So I have the following query

```
SELECT contact.account_id AS accountid,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE date_trunc('month'::text, activity.start_date) = date_trunc('month'::text, CURRENT_DATE - '1 mon'::interval)) AS last_month,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE date_trunc('month'::text, activity.start_date) = date_trunc('month'::text, CURRENT_DATE - '2 mons'::interval)) AS prev_month
FROM activity
JOIN activity_contact ON activity_contact.activity_id = activity.id
JOIN contact ON contact.id = activity_contact.contact_id
JOIN account ON contact.account_id = account.id
GROUP BY contact.account_id;
```

This returns:

```
accountid   last_month  prev_month
    1           3           1
```

However this is incorrect. There are only 3 activities, its just that each contact sees activity 1. so it is counting that activity twice. Is there a way for me to only count each activity id one time so there is no duplication?

Comment: replace `count(*)` by `count(DISTINCT activity_id)`

Comment: Fantastic stuff chief. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count(DISTINCT activity_id)` to fold duplicates in the count, [like Edouard suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70296132/ensuring-no-dupe-ids-in-query-return/70297085#comment124264586_70296132).
But there is more:

```sql
SELECT con.account_id AS accountid
     , count(DISTINCT aco.activity_id) FILTER (WHERE act.start_date >= date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '1 mon')
                                               AND   act.start_date <  date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP)) AS last_month
     , count(DISTINCT aco.activity_id) FILTER (WHERE act.start_date >= date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '2 mon')
                                               AND   act.start_date <  date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '1 mon')) AS prev_month
FROM   activity         act
JOIN   activity_contact aco ON aco.activity_id = act.id
                           AND act.start_date >= date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '2 mon')
                           AND act.start_date <  date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP)
RIGHT  JOIN contact     con ON con.id = aco.contact_id
-- JOIN   account       acc ON con.account_id = acc.id  -- noise
GROUP  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0bd2f1ea61219053381fe5eec46650bb)*

- Most importantly, add an outer `WHERE` clause to the query to filter irrelevant rows early. This can make a *big* difference for a small selection from a big table.
  We have to move that predicate to the `JOIN` clause, lest we'd exclude **accounts with no activity**. (`LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` can both be used, mirroring each other.)
  See:

  - [Postgres Left Join with where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465260/postgres-left-join-with-where-condition/40477254#40477254)
  - [Explain JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN and WHERE condition performance suggestion in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de/24876797#24876797)
- Make that filter "sargable", so it can use an index on `(start_date)` (unlike your original formulation). Again, big impact for a small selection from a big table.
- Use the same expressions for your aggregate filter clauses. Lesser effect, but take it.
  Unlike other aggregate functions, `count()` returns `0` (not `NULL`) for "no rows", so we don't have to do anything extra.
- Assuming referential integrity (enforced with a FK constraint), the join to table `account` is just expensive noise. Drop it.
  `CURRENT_DATE` is not wrong. But since your expressions yield `timestamp` anyway, it's  bit more efficient to use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` to begin with.

Compare with your original to see that this is quite a bit faster.

And I assume you are aware that this query introduces a dependency on the `TimeZone` setting of the executing session. The current date depends on where in the world we ask. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

---

If you are not bound to this particular output format, a pivoted form is simpler, now that we filter rows early:

```sql
SELECT con.account_id AS accountid
     , date_trunc('month', act.start_date) AS mon
     , count(DISTINCT aco.activity_id) AS dist_count
FROM   activity         act
JOIN   activity_contact aco ON aco.activity_id = act.id
                           AND act.start_date >= date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '2 mon')
                           AND act.start_date <  date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP)
RIGHT  JOIN  contact    con ON con.id = aco.contact_id
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2 DESC;
```

Again, we can include accounts without activity. But months without activity do not show up ...

Comment: thanks. yeah i noticed the timezone issue yesterday. thats on the list of things to fix. Ill have a look at that link. Cheers

Comment: @discodowney: Either work with `timestamptz` or define the time zone *explicitly* (and hence the resulting date) for the query to get rid of the dependency (and possible corner case errors). Added an alt query while being at it.

Comment: thats interesting. the format is done to make the go server parsing as easy as possible but its good to see this. ill have a think about whats best. Thanks for the help

Comment: one further question. If i added a second account but added no activities, but i wanted it to show in the result with a count of 0 in both. Could i do that? im not seeing how i would manage it, im thinking id need a separate query for that calculation

Comment: @discodowney: All doable in a single query with `LEFT JOIN`. You add an account with no activities. With or without entries in table `contact`?

Comment: The account will have contacts, yes

Comment: @discodowney: I update the answer to include accounts with no activity, as it fits in easily. Next time, please just ask another *question*. You can always link to earlier questions for context.