# How to differentiate between no rows and foreign key reference not existing?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

My `users` table contains Alice, Bob and Charles. Alice and Bob have a 3 and 2 `fruits` respectively. Charles has none. A relationship is established using a foreign key constraint `foreign key (user_id) references users (id)` and a `unique (user_id, name)` constraint, allowing zero or one fruit per user.

```sql
create table users (
  id         integer primary key,
  firstname  varchar(64)
);

create table fruits (
  id          integer primary key not null,
  user_id     integer not null,
  name        varchar(64) not null,
  foreign key (user_id) references users (id),
  unique (user_id, name)
);

insert into users (id, firstname) values (1, 'Alice');
insert into users (id, firstname) values (2, 'Bob');
insert into users (id, firstname) values (3, 'Charles');

insert into fruits (id, user_id, name) values (1, 1, 'grape');
insert into fruits (id, user_id, name) values (2, 1, 'apple');
insert into fruits (id, user_id, name) values (3, 1, 'pear');
insert into fruits (id, user_id, name) values (4, 2, 'orange');
insert into fruits (id, user_id, name) values (5, 2, 'cherry');
```

Charles does not have an orange, so there is no resulting row (first query below). However, running the same query for a user that does not exist (second query below) also returns no result.

```
test=# select * from fruits where user_id = 3 and name = 'orange';
 id | user_id | name 
----+---------+------
(0 rows)

test=# select * from fruits where user_id = 99 and name = 'orange';
 id | user_id | name 
----+---------+------
(0 rows)
```

Is it possible to perform a single query whilst simultaneously differentiating between the user not existing vs the user existing and not having a fruit?

If so, can this also be done to find all the fruits belonging to a particular user (i.e. `select * from fruits where user_id = 3` vs `select * from fruits where user_id = 99`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.2):

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, f.name AS fruit
--   , COALESCE(f.name, '') AS fruit  -- alternatively an empty string
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN fruits f ON f.user_id = u.id
                    AND f.name = 'orange'
WHERE  u.id = 3;
```

If the user exists, you always get a row.
If the user has no fruit (of that name), `fruit` defaults to `NULL` - which is otherwise impossible since `fruit.name` is defined `NOT NULL`.

To get an empty string instead, throw in [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). But no fruit can be named `''` then or it'll be ambiguous again. Add a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) to be sure.

Related:

- [Postgres Left Join with where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465260/postgres-left-join-with-where-condition/40477254#40477254)

Aside 1: "name" is not a good name.
Aside 2: Typically, this would be a many-to-many design with three tables: "users", "fruits" and "user_fruits". See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: This is great, thanks. With the application I have a struct that defines the Fruit field as type string (as opposed to a *string - "pointer to string"). Will I have to define a separate FruitRow struct using pointers, or is there a way in Postgres to have the NULL fruit values be converted to empty strings?

Comment: @AndyFusniak: Use `COALESCE` - consider the update.