# How to differentiate between empty result set versus non existent foreign key relation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

In my application `projects` has a one-to-many relationship with `widgets`. Each project contains many widgets.

Within my application I key a widget as using composite key (code, slug), i.e. `(p1, w2)` and `(p2, w2)` are distinct. Project `p1` has its own widget `w2` and project `p2` has a different widget `w2` with the same code. This provides separate scope for project owners.

I want a query that will get a widget by composite key, and at the same time distinguish whether the `projects.slug` does not match versus the `widgets.code` not matching.

Here's what I've tried so far. The WHERE clause filters for a specific project slug and widget code but isn't able to determine if the projects `slug` is missing or the widgets `code` is missing.

The first query below returns an empty result because there is no `w2` widget for project `p3`. However, the second query below returns also an empty result set, but for a different reason; the project slug does not exist in the projects table.

```sql
test=# SELECT p.id, p.slug, COALESCE(w.id, 0) id, COALESCE(w.code, '') code
FROM projects p LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets w ON p.id = w.project_id
WHERE p.slug = 'p3' AND code = 'w2';
id | slug | id | code 
----+------+----+------
(0 rows)

test=# SELECT p.id, p.slug, COALESCE(w.id, 0) id, COALESCE(w.code, '') code
FROM projects p LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets w ON p.id = w.project_id
WHERE p.slug = 'missing-project' AND code = 'w2';
 id | slug | id | code 
----+------+----+------
(0 rows)
```

What query will yield a result that can differentiate a non-existent project slug, an existent project with non-existent widget code and a complete match for both project slug and widget code?

---

### Background to this question:

I've learned how to do this using a query to fetch all widgets for a project. ([How to differentiate between no rows and foreign key reference not existing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896662/how-to-differentiate-between-no-rows-and-foreign-key-reference-not-existing))

If I use a query with only the slug I detect when a project is missing (empty result set - 2nd statement below) versus the project being there but having no widgets (1 row with empty id column - 3rd statement below).

```sql
test=# SELECT p.id, p.slug, COALESCE(w.id, 0) id, COALESCE(w.code, '') code
FROM projects p LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets w ON p.id = w.project_id 
WHERE p.slug = 'p1';
 id | slug | id | code 
----+------+----------+----------
  1 | p1   | 51 | w1
  1 | p1   | 52 | w2
(2 rows)


test=# SELECT p.id, p.slug, COALESCE(w.id, 0) id, COALESCE(w.code, '') code
FROM projects p LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets w ON p.id = w.project_id 
WHERE p.slug = 'p3';
 id | slug | id | code 
----+------+----+------
  3 | p3   |  0 | 
(1 row)


test=# SELECT p.id, p.slug, COALESCE(w.id, 0) id, COALESCE(w.code, '') code
FROM projects p LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets w ON p.id = w.project_id 
WHERE p.slug = 'missing-project';
 id | slug | id | code 
----+------+----+------
(0 rows)
```

```sql
SELECT
  p.id, p.slug, COALESCE(w.id, 0), COALESCE(w.code, '')
FROM projects p
LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets w
  ON p.id = w.project_id
WHERE p.slug = 'p4';
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id    INTEGER,
  slug  VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE widgets (
  id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
  project_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  code        VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, project_id),

  CONSTRAINT widgets_project_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (project_id)
     REFERENCES projects (id)
);

INSERT INTO projects (id, slug) VALUES (1, 'p1');
INSERT INTO projects (id, slug) VALUES (2, 'p2');
INSERT INTO projects (id, slug) values (3, 'p3');

INSERT INTO widgets (id, project_id, code) VALUES (51, 1, 'w1');
INSERT INTO widgets (id, project_id, code) VALUES (52, 1, 'w2');
INSERT INTO widgets (id, project_id, code) VALUES (53, 2, 'w2');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well there are three cases you want to differentiate:

1. The project and widget exist.
2. The project exists but the widget doesn't.
3. The project does not exist.

If that's a correct description of the cases, you can place the widget search in the `ON` clause of the join, and place the project search in the `WHERE` clause of the query.

For example:

```
SELECT
  p.id, 
  p.slug, 
  COALESCE(w.id, 0) as id, 
  COALESCE(w.code, '') as code
FROM projects p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets w ON p.id = w.project_id 
                         AND w.code = 'w1' -- widget code
where p.slug = 'p3' -- project code
```

Case #1 Result:

```
id  slug  id  code
--  ----  --  ----
 1  p3    10  w1
```

Case #2 Result:

```
id  slug  id  code
--  ----  --  ----
 1  p3    10  <null>
```

Case #3 Result:

```
id  slug  id  code
--  ----  --  ----
-- 0 rows returned
```

Though it still returns a row, case #2 can be differentiated from case #1 by the `code` column showing up as null. Case #3 does not return any row at all.

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LvrruFw7).

The problem with your original approach was that the `WHERE` condition `w.code = 'w2'` effectively turned your left outer join into an inner join: any result that had NULLs on the `widget` side would be eliminated by that condition. That's why you never got these results. If you put that condition in the join condition instead, it will not eliminate such results. The reason for that is the way left outer joins are defined: they are the result of the inner join plus and row from the left side that is missing in the result, supplemented with NULLs on the right side. Your condition would have eliminated the row from the inner join, so it appears in the result with NULLs on the `widget` side.

Comment: This does exactly what I'm after, so thank you.  My web API will be able to return 404 project-not-found or 404 widget-not-found to the caller. What exactly happens when the w.code = 'w1' clause  is moved to the ON rather than the WHERE?

Comment: I took the liberty to add an explanation.

Comment: This might not be the place to ask as it may deserve a separate question. How would I apply the same principle to DELETE and UPDATE for a widget. That is, being able to attempt the DELETE/UPDATE and detect the same three conditions?

Comment: Yes, that is a different question. It would be good if you rolled back your edits, so that the accepted answer matches your question.