# UPDATE rows only where a matching row exists in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table named `qc` only when `first.value` is equal to `second.value`.

An `UPDATE` query without `FROM` updates every value which is not what I want. I tried this, but it's still not working:

```sql
UPDATE qc
SET value = 
CASE 
   WHEN value < 125 THEN 
   CASE WHEN material LIKE 'Beton%' 
   THEN 40
   ELSE
   (CAST(value - 40 AS DECIMAL(5,2)))
   
   END
   WHEN value >= 125 AND value <= 150 THEN
   CASE WHEN material LIKE 'Beton%'
   THEN 50
   ELSE
   (CAST(value - 50 AS DECIMAL(5,2)))
   END
   
   ELSE 
   CASE WHEN material LIKE 'Beton%'
   THEN 80
   ELSE
   (CAST(value - 80 AS DECIMAL(5,2)))
   END
END
FROM (SELECT location, value
      FROM qc
      LEFT JOIN designlocation dl ON qc.designlocationid = dl.designlocationid

      WHERE material LIKE 'Beton_v%' AND value != '') first

   , (SELECT location, value
      FROM qc
      LEFT JOIN designlocation dl ON qc.designlocationid = dl.designlocationid
      WHERE material LIKE '%(3rd pass)%' AND value !='') second
WHERE first.location = second.location AND first.value = second.value;
```

Comment: Does you update run? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried the oldschool `UPDATE a,b,c SET a.x = 1 WHERE a.y = b.z AND b.id = c.id AND c.type = "Beton"` type of UPDATE which joins several tables ?

Comment: Share table schema with some data so it would be helpful to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE qc
SET    value = CASE
               WHEN dl.material LIKE 'Beton\_v%' THEN
                  CASE
                  WHEN qc.value < 125               THEN '40'::numeric(5,2)
                  WHEN qc.value BETWEEN 125 AND 150 THEN '50'::numeric(5,2)
                  ELSE                                   '80'::numeric(5,2)
                  END
               ELSE
                  CASE
                  WHEN qc.value < 125               THEN (qc.value - 40)::numeric(5,2)
                  WHEN qc.value BETWEEN 125 AND 150 THEN (qc.value - 50)::numeric(5,2)
                  ELSE                                   (qc.value - 80)::numeric(5,2)
                  END
               END
FROM   designlocation dl
,      qc qc2
JOIN   designlocation dl2 USING (designlocationid)
WHERE  qc.designlocationid = dl.designlocationid
AND    dl.material  LIKE ANY ('{Beton\_v%, %(3rd pass)%}')  -- array with 2 patterns
AND    dl2.material LIKE ANY ('{Beton\_v%, %(3rd pass)%}')
AND    dl2.material <> dl.material
AND    qc.value <> ''
AND    qc2.location = qc.location
AND    qc2.value    = qc.value
);
```

Why `Beton_v%` vs. `Beton%`? Assuming a typo, going with the more restrictive pattern. The character `_` has special meaning in a `LIKE` pattern. I escaped it to make it a literal `_`. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

Both `LEFT JOIN` in your original query are fake and can be replaced with `INNER JOIN`. See:

- [Postgres LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465260/postgres-left-join-with-where-condition/40477254#40477254)

This query only updates rows where at least one sibling row exists with identical `(location, value)`, but different `material` - being `LIKE` one of `('Beton\_v%', '%(3rd pass)%')`.

If there are more rows like that, all of them are updated (and possibly repeatedly). That would probably be a data error and / or we'd use a different query. I can only speculate as there is no information.

Comment: material and location are coming from different tables. Which I forgot to mention. My bad

Comment: Next time please start a new question. Don't change the nature of a question after answers have been given.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE qc
SET    value = CASE
               WHEN dl.material LIKE 'Beton\_v%' THEN
                  CASE
                  WHEN qc.value < 125               THEN '40'::numeric(5,2)
                  WHEN qc.value BETWEEN 125 AND 150 THEN '50'::numeric(5,2)
                  ELSE                                   '80'::numeric(5,2)
                  END
               ELSE
                  CASE
                  WHEN qc.value < 125               THEN (qc.value - 40)::numeric(5,2)
                  WHEN qc.value BETWEEN 125 AND 150 THEN (qc.value - 50)::numeric(5,2)
                  ELSE                                   (qc.value - 80)::numeric(5,2)
                  END
               END
FROM   designlocation dl
,      qc qc2
JOIN   designlocation dl2 USING (designlocationid)
WHERE  qc.designlocationid = dl.designlocationid
AND    dl.material  LIKE ANY ('{Beton\_v%, %(3rd pass)%}')  -- array with 2 patterns
AND    dl2.material LIKE ANY ('{Beton\_v%, %(3rd pass)%}')
AND    dl2.material <> dl.material
AND    qc.value <> ''
AND    qc2.location = qc.location
AND    qc2.value    = qc.value
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).