# Returning json array/object of nested data

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a postgres database of jobs, locations and countries, where `jobs <=> locations` is many-to-many, `jobs <=> countries` is many-to-many, and `locations <= countries` is one-to-many. A job can belong to a country through 2 different paths:

```
jobs <=> jobs_locations <=> locations <=> countries
jobs <=> jobs_countries <=> countries
```

This is my current query:

```sql
select
  jobs.*,
  COALESCE(json_agg(locations) filter (where locations.id IS NOT NULL), '[]') as locations,
  COALESCE(json_agg(countries) filter (where countries.id IS NOT NULL), '[]') as countries
from jobs
left join jobs_locations on jobs.id = jobs_locations.job_id
left join locations on jobs_locations.location_id = locations.id
left join countries loc_country on locations.country_id = loc_country.id
left join jobs_countries on jobs.id = jobs_countries.job_id
left join countries on jobs_countries.country_id = countries.id
where loc_country.id = 2 OR countries.id = 2
group by jobs.id;
```

I'm currently getting the data in this format:

```
{
  id: 1,
  ...
  locations: [
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "Paris",
      country_id: 100
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get a job in this format:

```
{
  id: 1,
  ...
  locations: [
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "Paris",
      country: {
        id: 100,
        name: "France"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do this? It seems like a simple query but I've been trying for hours to get this data in the right format, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Many ways lead to Rome.

This returns all jobs, and only appends locations and/or countries for `country_id = 2`. Should be among the fastest ways:

```sql
SELECT j.*
     , coalesce(l.locations, '[]') AS locations
     , coalesce(c.countries, '[]') AS countries
FROM   jobs j
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT jl.job_id AS id
        , jsonb_agg(l) - 'country_id' AS locations  -- !!!
   FROM   jobs_locations jl
   JOIN  (
      SELECT l.*, to_jsonb(c) AS country            -- subquery to prepare row !!!
      FROM   locations l
      JOIN   countries c ON c.id = l.country_id
      WHERE  l.country_id = 2
      ) l ON l.id = jl.location_id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) l USING (id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT jc.job_id AS id
        , jsonb_agg(c) AS countries
   FROM   jobs_countries jc
   JOIN   countries c ON c.id = jc.country_id
   WHERE  jc.country_id = 2
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id);
```

First of, your original seems incorrect to begin with. Multiple uncorrelated `LEFT JOIN` instances result in multiplication of rows. See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

And then you add a `WHERE` condition on "right" tables, which counteracts all the `LEFT JOIN` clauses ... See:

- [Postgres LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465260/postgres-left-join-with-where-condition/40477254#40477254)

I fixed that before adding an answer to your question. Note how I use `jsonb` instead of `json` to allow convenient operators. Details for that solution:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)
- [How to select sub-object with given keys from JSONB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290029/3684)

One side-effect: keys appear in `jsonb`-specific sort order.

#### Only get jobs with countries and/or locations

At least one of the of the joins must find a row. (That's how I understand [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146930/returning-json-array-object-of-nested-data/74147281?noredirect=1#comment130930666_74147281).)

You *could* simply append your (adapted) original `WHERE` clause in the outer `SELECT`:

```sql
...
WHERE 2 IN (l.id, c.id);
```

But try this more elegant rewrite with a `FULL JOIN` between locations and countries, followed by a `JOIN` to `jobs`. If the subqueries are selective (like it seems), that should be (much) faster because it can filter jobs right away, during the join on the PK column `id`:

```sql
SELECT j.*
     , coalesce(l.locations, '[]') AS locations
     , coalesce(c.countries, '[]') AS countries
FROM  (
   SELECT jl.job_id AS id
        , jsonb_agg(l) - 'country_id' AS locations
   FROM   jobs_locations jl
   JOIN  (
      SELECT l.*, to_jsonb(c) AS country
      FROM   locations l
      JOIN   countries c ON c.id = l.country_id
      WHERE  l.country_id = 2
      ) l ON l.id = jl.location_id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) l
FULL   JOIN (
   SELECT jc.job_id AS id
        , jsonb_agg(c) AS countries
   FROM   jobs_countries jc
   JOIN   countries c ON c.id = jc.country_id
   WHERE  jc.country_id = 2
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id)
JOIN   jobs j USING (id);
```

You should be comfortable with all join clauses and `NULL` handling to understand subtleties. In particular, matching column aliases (`id`) and the `USING` clause in the [`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.4.3.2.4.1.3.1.2) are essential to produce the single, combined `id` column for the subsequent `[INNER] JOIN`. This is one of the rare cases where the `USING` clause is essential.
(Well, we could spell out `JOIN jobs j ON j.id = COALESCE(l.id, c.id)` but that's far less elegant.)

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful! And thanks for the tips. It looks like this query also returns jobs that have no locations/countries set. I'm assuming this is because they're both left joins and so will return the row if neither present. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: @tiimgreen. There is. I added alternatives and some more explanation. Your question does not specify the desired result exactly. Nor are there exact table definitions, Postgres version and a fiddle, which would help and clarify a lot.