# How to restrict the result of a left join and use it for the next left join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

My query goes over three entities, so I have two left joins. I want to restrict the result of the first join. For example we have customers and order evaluations. In the first join I want only the youngest order evaluation that is hanging onto the customer. The older ones don't interest me. After this I join over another table (with dependency to customer and orderevaluation) and ask for certain conditions. I can't seem to find out how I can restrict the first join result with the help of the createstamp.

My query draft looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
left join (SELECT * FROM orderevaluation ORDER BY createstamp desc LIMIT 1) o on customer.id = o.customer_id
left join ... WHERE ... AND ... ;
```

Here is the problem that there gets only one orderevaluation selected for all my orders and not one per order.
I want to select the youngest orderevaluation per customer and then join again.

I also tried:

Selecting after the

```
customer.id =
```

But there I could only work with the `id` and not with the `createstamp`.

I tried to use `ORDER BY o.createstamp DESC limit 1` after the `WHERE` condition but it doesn't work, either.

Comment: Crucial for the optimal query: do you run it for one or a few selected customers, or for most or all of the table at once?

Comment: After the two left joins I have like four conditions for the customers that get selected but for the joins the whole customer-table is used, is it not? The conditions are all dependent on the other two entities, like the createstamp for the orderevaluation is not older than x and so one

Comment: That sounds like a broken query. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477254/939860

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you run such a query for one or a **few** selected customers (filtered in the undisclosed outer `WHERE` clause). Then, a `LATERAL` subquery is typically fastest, as it only processes the few customers of interest instead of the whole table.

```
SELECT ...
FROM   customer c
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT o.*
   FROM   orderevaluation o
   WHERE  o.customer_id = c.id
   ORDER  BY o.customer_id, o.createstamp DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) o ON true
LEFT  JOIN ... 
WHERE ...  -- filtering *few* customers
```

See:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)

About the `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Be sure to have an **index** with leading `customer_id`, ideally on `orderevaluation(customer_id, customer_id, createstamp DESC NULLS LAST)`.

Drop `NULLS LAST` from index and query if the column is defined `NOT NULL`.

For additional joins, consider:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select the youngest orderevaluation per customer and then join again.

You would typically filter the first table in a subquery. In Postgres, one  approach uses `distinct on`. Starting from your pseudo-code:

```
SELECT ...  -- enumerate wanted cols here 
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_id) o.*
    FROM orderevaluation o
    ORDER BY customer_id, createstamp DESC
) o on customer.id = o.customer_id
LEFR JOIN ... 
WHERE ...
```

Another approach would be to use lateral joins instead of left joins (and then we could indeed use `limit`, as in your attempt) - which would require more context about the design of your tables.