# How to get the latest entry in a month for each student

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the category of specific students health inspection for each month. However, sometimes there are multiple entries for a month. How do I get the latest entry for the month using SQL?

Below is the SQL I am using:

```sql
SELECT  mt_tagged_student.student_id, 
        mt_inspection.category,
        mt_inspection.created_date as entry_date
FROM public.mt_tagged_student
        LEFT JOIN public.mt_student  On mt_tagged_student.student_id = mt_student.id
        LEFT JOIN public.mt_inspection  On mt_inspection.student_id = mt_student.id
where mt_inspection.created_date between '2023-10-1 00:00:01' AND '2023-10-31 23:59:59'
    and mt_inspection.category = 1
ORDER BY mt_tagged_student.student_id ASC, entry_date Desc
```

Here's some of the result of the SQL,

[image]

The highlighted one show that sometimes there are two entries in a month. How do I get the latest entry of that month only?

Comment: [DO NOT use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A textbook example for `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (student_id)
       student_id
     , i.category
     , i.created_date AS entry_date
FROM   public.mt_tagged_student t
JOIN   public.mt_student    s USING (student_id)
JOIN   public.mt_inspection i USING (student_id)
WHERE  i.created_date >= '2023-10-1'
AND    i.created_date <  '2023-11-1'
AND    i.category = 1
ORDER  BY student_id, i.created_date DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Should also perform best for just a couple entries max per month like you indicate. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Also, [don't use `BETWEEN` with timestamps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29).

I converted both instances of `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to plain `[INNER] JOIN` because the former make no sense in combination with `WHERE` conditions on the right table. See:

- [Postgres LEFT JOIN with WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465260/postgres-left-join-with-where-condition/40477254#40477254)

I threw in `DESC NULLS LAST` at first, because the `LEFT JOIN` can introduce null values. That's removed now, but we still don't know whether `created_date` itself is defined `NOT NULL`. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

`USING` instead of `ON` is a totally optional syntax shortcut. But I warmly recommend using table aliases as demonstrated to cut down on the noise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT  mt_tagged_student.student_id, 
        mi.category,
        mi.created_date as entry_date
FROM public.mt_tagged_student
        LEFT JOIN public.mt_student  On mt_tagged_student.student_id = mt_student.id
        LEFT JOIN public.mt_inspection mi On mi.student_id = mt_student.id
where mi.created_date between '2023-10-1 00:00:01' AND '2023-10-31 23:59:59'
    and mi.category = 1
    and not exists (select 1 from public.mt_inspection mi 
                   where mi.student_id = mii.student_id
                   and date_trunc('month', mi.created_date) = date_trunc('month', mii.created_date)
                   and mii.created_date > mi.created_date
                   and mii.category = 1)
ORDER BY mt_tagged_student.student_id ASC, entry_date Desc
```

OR you can use `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```
select t.student_id, t.category, t.entry_date from
(SELECT      mt_tagged_student.student_id, 
            mt_inspection.category,
            mt_inspection.created_date as entry_date,
            row_number() over (partition by mt_tagged_student.student_id, date_trunc('month', mt_inspection.created_date) order by mt_inspection.created_date desc) as rn
    FROM public.mt_tagged_student
            LEFT JOIN public.mt_student  On mt_tagged_student.student_id = mt_student.id
            LEFT JOIN public.mt_inspection  On mt_inspection.student_id = mt_student.id
    where mt_inspection.created_date between '2023-10-1 00:00:01' AND '2023-10-31 23:59:59'
        and mt_inspection.category = 1) t
    ORDER BY t.student_id ASC, t.entry_date Desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ranked_inspection AS (
    SELECT
        mt_tagged_student.student_id,
        mt_inspection.category,
        mt_inspection.created_date AS entry_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mt_tagged_student.student_id
                           ORDER BY mt_inspection.created_date DESC) AS rnk
    FROM
        public.mt_tagged_student
        LEFT JOIN public.mt_student ON mt_tagged_student.student_id = mt_student.id
        LEFT JOIN public.mt_inspection ON mt_inspection.student_id = mt_student.id
    WHERE
        mt_inspection.created_date >= '2023-10-1'
        AND mt_inspection.created_date <  '2023-11-1'
        AND mt_inspection.category = 1
)
SELECT
    student_id,
    category,
    entry_date
FROM
    ranked_inspection
WHERE
    rnk = 1
ORDER BY
    student_id ASC, entry_date DESC;
```