How to optimize a query when joining two tables?
My system is using PostgreSQL as the database. I am encountering an issue when using a query to join two large tables together. I'll briefly describe the tables as follows:
Location:
- id: uuid
- name: string (indexes)
- country: string (indexes)
- number: string

Product:
- id: uuid
- name: string
- score: number (indexes)
- rate: number (indexes)
- report: number (indexes)
- lock: boolean (indexes)
- location_id: uuid (not null) (indexes)

Location and Product will be in a 1-1 relation unique. Location can have a product - or not.
I used this query:
select 
    l.id, l.name, l.number, 
    p.id as pId, p.name, p.score, p.rate
from
    location l
left join 
    product p on p.location_id = l.id
where 
    l.country = 'US'
    and l.id < 'xxx-yyy-zzz'
    and (p.name is not null or l.name is not null)
    and p.score > 1 and p.rate > 4 and p.lock = false
order by 
    id desc
limit 100

This is the Explain analyzed:
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Limit  (cost=0.86..176.73 rows=100 width=81) (actual time=234.211..1765.086 rows=100 loops=1)                                                                                                    |
|  ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.86..975290.35 rows=554575 width=81) (actual time=234.210..1764.985 rows=100 loops=1)                                                                                   |
|        Merge Cond: (l.id = p.location_id)                                                                                                                                                             |
|        Join Filter: ((l.name IS NOT NULL) OR (p.name IS NOT NULL))                                                                                                                           |
|        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3492                                                                                                                                                        |
|        ->  Index Scan Backward using "PK_c16f58426537a660b3f2a26e983" on location l  (cost=0.43..504099.86 rows=2444771 width=43) (actual time=1.035..1282.591 rows=3668 loops=1)          |
|              Index Cond: (id < 'ffbe90da-429a-4e79-99c8-b3ef9ac64b2d'::uuid)                                                                                                                    |
|              Filter: ((country)::text = 'US'::text)                                                                                                                                             |
|              Rows Removed by Filter: 3920                                                                                                                                                       |
|        ->  Index Scan Backward using "PK_fa791fa9c903bb99bbcebde4878" on product p  (cost=0.43..455544.85 rows=1653751 width=38) (actual time=0.586..473.972 rows=12362 loops=1)|
|              Filter: ((NOT lock) AND (COALESCE(score, 0) > 1) AND (COALESCE(rate, 0) > 4))                                                                             |
|              Rows Removed by Filter: 167                                                                                                                                                        |
|Planning Time: 30.386 ms                                                                                                                                                                         |
|Execution Time: 1765.250 ms                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Note that both the product and location tables have a very large number of rows. Each table contains around several million to tens of millions of rows.
How can I speed up the query execution? For some countries, it runs very fast, but for others, it runs slowly, even though there are fewer rows.

For starters, the query string is contradictory. You combine a LEFT JOIN with WHERE conditions on the right table, which makes no sense. Now it's not clear what you want precisely. Currently, you effectively get an inner join, but maybe you wanted an actual left join ... See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477254/939860. Other than that, please provide proper information for your performance question as instructed here

You need to add the actual table definitions (ddl) and the result of explain (analyze , verbose, buffers). Add all as an update to your question and as text - no images. You can change left join to a simple join as any rows from location retained as a result of left joining are discarded by the predicates on product.  BTW * tens of millions of roes* is not a very large table.

Please review [mre]. Actual table DDL (including index definitions), is much more useful than informal descriptions. Having both DDL and example data (provided as executable SQL) makes it much easier for others to setup the problem and helps avoid ambiguity. Quantitative measures (as provided by EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) is much more useful than qualitative assessments.

The and p.sore > 1 and p.rate > 4 and p.lock = false expressions effectively convert the left join into an inner join. Did you mean to have those as part of the join conditions?

Move the right table's conditions into the join clause:
select
  l.id, l.name, l.number, p.id as pId, p.name, p.score, p.rate
from location l
left join product p on p.location_id = l.id
  and (p.name is not null or l.name is not null)
  and p.score > 1 and p.rate > 4 and p.lock = false
where l.country = 'US'
  and l.id < 'xxx-yyy-zzz'
order by id desc
limit 100

and create a covering index (has all columns needed, in optimal order) on product:
create index product_1 on product(location_id, lock, score, rate, name);

and this index on location is assist both where and order by clauses:
create index idx_location_country_id on location(country, id desc);


Try those two indexes :
CREATE INDEX X001 ON product (rate, score, location_id) INCLUDE (id, name)
   WHERE lock = false;

CREATE INDEX X002 ON location (country, id) INCLUDE (name, number);

They will be covering and the first is pre filtered on "lock = false"
My be you can filter the second one with "country = 'US'" if a majority of queries ask for US contry...
