# How to merge 2 queries together in same query but different columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, null, window-functions

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.9 to run two different queries that give different results but both group by "month-year". I was wondering how I would create a query to give me the same data in *one* table?

Query 1:

```
SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startedPayingDate), '-', 
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startedPayingDate)) AS "Month", 
 COUNT(*) AS "Total AB Paying Customers"
FROM (       
 SELECT cm.customer_id, MIN(cm.created_at) AS startedPayingDate 
 FROM customerusermap AS cm, users as u
 WHERE cm.customer_id = u.customer_id AND cm.user_id<>u.id 
 GROUP BY cm.customer_id ) AS t
GROUP BY 1, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startedPayingDate), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startedPayingDate)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startedPayingDate), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startedPayingDate);
```

Results in something like this:

```
Month  | Total AB Paying Customers
---------------------------------
3-2014 | 2
4-2014 | 4
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT concat(extract(MONTH from u.created_at),'-',extract(year from u.created_at)) as "Month", 
count(u.email) as "Total SMB Paying Customers"
FROM customerusermap AS cm, users AS u 
WHERE cm.customer_id = u.customer_id AND cm.user_id = u.id AND u.paid_status = 'paying' 
GROUP by 1,extract(month from u.created_at),extract(year from u.created_at)
order by extract(year from u.created_at),extract(month from u.created_at);
```

Results in something like this:

```
Month  | Total SMB Paying Customers
-----------------------------------
2-2014 | 3
3-2014 | 8
4-2014 | 5
```

#### Desired result

I want to merge these two queries into something that results as shown and also orders by year and month (i.e. oldest to newest):

```
Month  | Total AB Paying Customers | Total SMB Paying Customers | Total | Cumulative
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2-2014 |           0               |            3               |    3  |   3
3-2014 |           2               |            8               |    10 |   13
4-2014 |           4               |            5               |    9  |   22
```

#### Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id serial NOT NULL,
firstname character varying(255) NOT NULL,
lastname character varying(255) NOT NULL,
email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
customer_id character varying(255) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
companyname character varying(255),
primary_user_id integer,
paid_status character varying(255),  -- updated from comment
CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT primary_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (primary_user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
CONSTRAINT users_uuid_key UNIQUE (uuid)
)
```

Whereas the customerusermap table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE customerusermap (
id serial NOT NULL,
user_id integer NOT NULL,
customer_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
CONSTRAINT customerusermap_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT customerusermap_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
CONSTRAINT customerusermap_user_id_key UNIQUE (user_id)
);
```

Comment: Table definition and your version of Postgres are missing. Both would be instrumental for the exact formulation of the query.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter my apologies for the confusion - I have added the create table scripts and the Postgres version

Comment: That works. I assume there is also a column `users.paid_status` that got lost in translation. `varchar NOT NULL` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General solution

The key feature would be a **[`FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)**, but handle NULL values properly:

```
SELECT *
     , "Total AB Paying Customers" + "Total SMB Paying Customers" AS "Total"
     , sum("Total AB Paying Customers" + "Total SMB Paying Customers")
         OVER (ORDER BY "Month") AS "Cumulative"
FROM  (
   SELECT "Month"
        , COALESCE(q1."Total AB Paying Customers", 0)  AS "Total AB Paying Customers"
        , COALESCE(q2."Total SMB Paying Customers", 0) AS "Total SMB Paying Customers"
   FROM      (<query1>) q1
   FULL JOIN (<query2>) q2 USING ("Month")
   ) sub;
```

Use `sum()` as a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) for the cumulative sum.
The additional subquery layer is only for convenience, so that we don't have to add `COALESCE()` more often than necessary.
The query could be simplified some more: format the month in the outer `SELECT`, etc.

### Optimized query

Based on your added setup:

```
SELECT to_char(mon, 'FMMM-YYYY') AS "Month"
     , ct_ab                     AS "Total AB Paying Customers"
     , ct_smb                    AS "Total SMB Paying Customers"
     , ct_ab + ct_smb            AS "Total"
     , sum(ct_ab + ct_smb) OVER (ORDER BY mon)::int AS "Cumulative"
FROM  (
   SELECT mon, COALESCE(q1.ct_ab, 0) AS ct_ab, COALESCE(q2.ct_smb, 0) AS ct_smb
   FROM  (
      SELECT date_trunc('month', start_date) AS mon, count(*)::int AS ct_ab
      FROM  (       
         SELECT cm.customer_id, min(cm.created_at) AS start_date 
         FROM   customerusermap cm
         JOIN   users u USING (customer_id)
         WHERE  cm.user_id <> u.id 
         GROUP  BY 1
         ) t
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) q1
   FULL JOIN (
      SELECT date_trunc('month', u.created_at) AS mon, count(*)::int AS ct_smb
      FROM   customerusermap cm
      JOIN   users u USING (customer_id)
      WHERE  cm.user_id = u.id AND u.paid_status = 'paying' 
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) q2 USING (mon)
   ) sub;
ORDER  BY mon;
```

#### Major points

- Use [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to format your month any way you like. And do it just *once* at the end. The [template pattern](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) `FMMM` produces month numbers without leading zero, like in your original.
- Use [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to granulate your `timestamp without time zone` to month resolution (first timestamp in the month, but that makes no difference here).
- I added `ORDER BY mon` to get the sort order like you commented. That works as expected since the column `mon` is still a `timestamp` (not converted to a string (`text`) yet.
- Since `u.email` is defined `NOT NULL`, `count(*)` does the same as `count(u.email)` in this context, a bit cheaper.
- Use explicit `JOIN` syntax. Same performance, but much clearer.
- I cast aggregated counts to `integer`. That's totally *optional* (and assuming you won't have an integer overflow). So you have all integer numbers in the result instead of `bigint` and `numeric`

Compare to your original, you will find this is substantially shorter and a faster.

If performance is important be sure to have indexes on relevant columns. If there are *many* entries in `users` to one entry in `customerusermap`, there are more sophisticated options with a `JOIN LATERAL` to make both your queries faster:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

If you want to include months without any activity, `LEFT JOIN` to a complete list of months instead. Example:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Comment: Oops disregard last comment - this works! How would I sort by date though? ie 10-2012, 11-2012, 12-2012, 1-2013. right now it is sorted by month-year so it is giving me 8-2013, 8-2014, 8-2015, 9-2013 etc

Comment: As I mentioned: do the formatting *after* everything else. Work with the `date` first, that's simpler and faster - and you get the order right.

Comment: Hey Erwin, thanks for the help. just to clarify, what do you mean by work with the `date` first? Should I separate the "Month" to be "Month" and "Year" rather than concatenating?

Comment: @AshleyI.: If you edit your question to provide the requested information (essential to every such question), I'll give you a superior complete query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91500/discussion-between-ashley-i-and-erwin-brandstetter).