# Run Postgres query that groups by one field and sorts by another

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a PostgreSQL table with the following relevant fields:

```
url
title
created_at
```

There can be many rows that contain identical URLs but different titles. Here are some sample rows:

```
www.nytimes.com | The New York Times         | 2016-01-01 00:00:00`
www.wsj.com     | The Wall Street Journal    | 2016-01-03 15:32:13`
www.nytimes.com | The New York Times Online  | 2016-01-06 07:19:08`
```

I'm trying to obtain an output that lists the following fields:

1) `url`
2) `title` that corresponds to the highest value of `created_at`
3) count of all `title` for that unique `url`

So, output rows for the above sample would look something like this:

```
www.nytimes.com | The New York Times Online | 2
www.wsj.com     | The Wall Street Journal   | 1
```

Based on the numerous SO posts I've read on similar questions, it looks like my best option for obtaining the first two fields (`url` and latest `title`) would be to use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
select distinct on (url) url, title from headlines order by url, created_at desc
```

Likewise, to obtain the first and third fields (`url` and count of all `title`), I could simply use `GROUP BY`:

```
select url, count(title) from headlines group by url
```

What I can't figure out is how to combine the above methodologies and obtain the above-mentioned three values I'm trying to get.

(Edited to provide more clarity.)

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provide sample data and expected output .

Comment: What about natural joining two queries you wrote?

Comment: Technically, the "most recent name" is part of the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try;

```
select t1.url, t2.title, t1.cnt
from (
  select url, count(title) cnt 
  from headlines 
  group by url
) t1
join (
  select distinct on (url) url, title 
  from headlines 
  order by url, created_at desc
) t2 on t1.url = t2.url
order by t1.url
```

`join` both queries on `url`

[**`sql fiddle demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f7665f/3)

Comment: I like both answers (yours and @Erwin's) but chose this one because it seems to run slightly faster on my dataset.

Comment: @jayp: Best performance depends on details of your setup and data distribution. There is no single query for this performing best in every case. [Details in the provided link .](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in a single `SELECT` with a single scan over the table -  by combining a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (url)
       url, title, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY url) AS ct 
FROM   headlines 
ORDER  BY url, created_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fbbea/2)

Related (with detailed explanation):

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.url,t1.title,t2.count from headlines t1 
inner join(
select url,count(*) as count,max(created_at) as created_at
from headlines group by url ) t2 on t1.url=t2.url and t1.created_at=t2.created_at;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f7665f/11