# count max values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, max

I have a problem to formulate an sql question in postgresql, hoping to get some help here

I have three tables employee, visitor, and visit.  I want to find out which employee (fk_employee_id) who have been responsible for most visit that haven't been checked out.

I want to make an sql question which are returning just the number one result, (by max function maybe?) instead of my current one, which are returning a ranked list (this ranked list doesn't work either if the number one position is shared by two persons)

This is my current sql question:

```
select visitor.fk_employee_id, count(visitor.fk_employee_id)

From Visit

Inner Join visitor on visit.fk_visitor_id = visitor.visitor_id
WHERE check_out_time IS NULL

group by visitor.fk_employee_id, visitor.fk_employee_id
Limit 1
```

Anyone now how to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Kce.png)

Comment: This question requires (at least) a table definition for `visit` (`CREATE TABLE` statement). And always your version of Postgres.

Comment: now I have attached an overview of mine tables in my question

Comment: Your added ER diagram seems broken. Are you sure it's correct? Add the definition of table `visit` to make things clear.

Comment: Visit table

PrimaryKey = visit_id
visit_date
visit_time_in
visit_time_out
check_in_time
check_out_time

ForeignKey = fk_employee_id (this is the person the visitor are going to meet)
ForeignKey = fk_visitor_id

Visitor table

In the visitor table I have information about the person who are visiting the company and which employee who are the responsible for the meeting this day (fk_employee_id)

I want to know which fk_employee_id in visitor who are responsible for the most meeting where check_out_time is null.

Comment: All defining information in the *question*, please. Not in comments. Comments are too hard to read and lost to the general public. The preferred form for a table definition is a valid `CREATE TABLE` statement, showing data types and constraints.

Comment: my question is solved thx anyway :-)

Comment: Thant's good to hear. This is a public website, though. Questions are supposed to be useful to the general public, not only for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid confusion, I will change the column names to:

- `visitor` table, the `FK to employee id` : `employee_in_charge_id`
- `visit` table, the `FK to employee id` : `employee_to_meet_id`

From your explanation in comments, you are looking for **Employee**, who has the **most visits** which are **not check-out** .

In the case where, more than 1 employees are having same max number of visits which are not check-out, this query lists all the multiple employees:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT
        r.employee_in_charge_id,
        count(*) cnt,
        rank() over (ORDER BY count(*) DESC)
    FROM visit v
        JOIN visitor r ON v.visitor_id = r.id
    WHERE v.check_out_time IS NULL
    GROUP BY r.employee_in_charge_id
) a

WHERE rank = 1;
```

Refer `SQLFidle` link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/423d9/2

**Side Note:**

To me, it sounds more correct if `employee_in_charge_id` is part of `visit` table, rather than `visitor` table. My assumption is for each `visit`, there is 1 employee (A) who is responsible to handle the visit, & the visitor is meeting 1 employee (B). So 1 visitor can make multiple visits, which handle by different employees.

Anyway, my answer above is based on your original schema design.

Comment: Hi

Thx for reply

This sql working if you want to count the number one ranked fk_employee_id in visit, not in visitor

In visit table I have a column called fk_visitor_id which is a foreign key to the table visitor, and the number of the meeting. Every meeting in the visitor table (every row) has a column called fk_employee_id which is the person who is responsible for the meeting, this is the one I want to find out the number one ranked. 

fk_employee_id in visit = the employee that will meet the visitor
fk_employee_id In visitor = the employee that are responsible for the meeting

Comment: Please show your table schema definition in question then.

Comment: Now I have attached my table schema in my question, probably should have done it directly instead of trying to explain in text ;-)

Comment: @Pete From my understanding, an `employee` is responsible for a `visitor`. A `visitor` make several `visit`. So why you still need `fk_employee_id` in `visit` table? Aren't this relation is already specified in `visitor` table? Still not clear to me, please provide sample data with expected output.

Comment: Hi. The employee (fk_employee_id) have two function in my tables. In the visit table it show which employee the visitor are going to meet, and in the visitor table it is the employee who are responsible for the visit, they don't have to be the same employee. Ex. Carl from Siemens is visiting my company X to meet Johan who works there (fk_employee in visit). This day Adam is the responsible for all the meeting in our company (fk_employe_id In visitor). So I want to find out which fk_employee_id in visitor who are responsible for the most meeting that haven't been checked out..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a standard n:m implementation like detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225), this whould be one way to do it:

```
SELECT fk_employee_id
FROM   visit
WHERE  check_out_time IS NULL
GROUP  BY fk_employee_id
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Assuming referential integrity, you do not need to include the table `visitor` in the query at all.

count(*) is a bit faster than `count(fk_employee_id)` doing the same in this case. (assuming `fk_employee_id` is `NOT NULL`). See:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

Comment: Hi. Thx for comment. the one I try to count is in visitor (fk_employee_id) so I have to include that table also. (See my diagram I attached to the question) So I assume I have to write som kind of join statement to solve it