# PostgreSQL optimize query performance that contains Window function with CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, window-functions, jsonb

Here the column `amenity_category` and `parent_path` is `JSONB` column with value like ["Tv","Air Condition"] and ["20000","20100","203"] respectively. Apart from that other columns are normal `varchar` and `numeric` type. I've around **2.5M rows** with primary key on `id` and it is indexed. Basically the initial **CTE** part is taking time when **rp.parent_path** match multiple rows.

**Sample dataset:**

[image]

**Current query:**

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT id,
  property_name,
  property_type_category,
  review_score, 
  amenity_category.name, 
  count(*) AS cnt FROM table_name rp, 
  jsonb_array_elements_text(rp.amenity_categories) amenity_category(name)
  WHERE rp.parent_path ? '203' AND number_of_review >= 1
  GROUP BY amenity_category.name,id 
),
CTE2 as
(
  SELECT id, property_name,property_type_category,name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY property_type_category,
  name ORDER BY review_score DESC),
  COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY property_type_category,
  name ORDER BY name DESC) 
  FROM CTE
)

SELECT id, property_name, property_type_category, name, COUNT 
FROM CTE2
where row_number = 1
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**So my basic question is is there any other way I can re-write this query or optimize the current query?**

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sir, I am trying to get count of each property_type_categories with its amenity combination windowing and get the top id and property_name along with it on each window.

Comment: for example if you see the  output, **Category: Cabin and Amenity: Tv has count of 273 and from that 273 I am grabbing the `id, property_name` value of TOP ROW**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's safe to assume that array elements in `amenity_categories` are distinct (no duplicate array elements), we can radically simplify to:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (property_type_category, ac.name)
       id, property_name, property_type_category, ac.name
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY property_type_category, ac.name) AS count
FROM   table_name rp, jsonb_array_elements_text(rp.amenity_categories) ac(name)
WHERE  parent_path ? '203'
AND    number_of_review >= 1
ORDER  BY property_type_category, ac.name, review_score DESC;
```

If `review_score` can be NULL, make that:

```sql
...
ORDER  BY property_type_category, ac.name, review_score DESC NULLS LAST;
```

This works, because `DISTINCT ON` is applied as last step (after window functions). See:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)

`parent_path` and `number_of_review` should probably be indexed. Depends on data distribution and selectivity of the `WHERE` conditions, which you didn't disclose.

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Assuming `id` is `NOT NULL`, `count(*)` is faster and equivalent to `count(id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir, I'll get back to you while checking this optimization. Really appreciate your answer.

Comment: It works and It's plan and execution time better than than previous.