# Getting counts for overlapping time periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, distinct, aggregation

I have a table `data` in PostgreSQL with this structure:

```
created_at.       customer_email               status
2020-12-31        xxx@gmail.com                opened
...
2020-12-24        yyy@gmail.com                delivered
2020-12-24        xxx@gmail.com                opened
...
2020-12-17        zzz@gmail.com                opened
2020-12-10        xxx@gmail.com                opened
2020-12-03        hhh@gmail.com                enqueued
2020-11-27        xxx@gmail.com                opened
...
2020-11-20        rrr@gmail.com                opened
2020-11-13        ttt@gmail.com                opened
```

There are many rows for each day.

Basically I need 2021-W01 for this week with the count of unique emails with status "opened" within the last 90 days. Likewise for every week before that.

**Desired output:**

```
period    active
2021-W01  1539
2020-W53  1480
2020-W52  1630
2020-W51  1820
2020-W50  1910
2020-W49  1890
2020-W48  2000
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) would come to mind. Alas, those don't allow `DISTINCT` aggregations.

Instead, get distinct counts from a `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
WITH weekly_dist AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('week', created_at) AS wk, customer_email
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  status = 'opened'
   )
SELECT to_char(t.wk, 'YYYY"-W"IW') AS period, ct.active
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('week', min(created_at) + interval '1 week')
                        , date_trunc('week', now()::timestamp)
                        , interval '1 week') AS wk   
   FROM   tbl
   ) t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT customer_email) AS active
   FROM   weekly_dist d
   WHERE  d.wk >= t.wk - interval '91 days'
   AND    d.wk <  t.wk
   ) ct ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dac7e1228972fb1b27333c8a7e51b900)*

I operate with `timestamp`, not `timestamptz`, might make a corner case difference.

The CTE `weekly_dist` reduces the set to distinct "opened" emails. This step is strictly optional, but increases performance significantly if there can be more than a few duplicates per week.

The derived table `t` generates a timestamp for the begin of each week since the earliest entry in the table up to "now". This way I make sure no week is skipped,even if there are no rows for it. See:

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)
- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

But I do skip the first week since I count active emails *before* each start of the week.

Then `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` to a subquery computing the distinct count for the 90-day time-range. To be precise, I deduct 91 days, and exclude the start of the current week. This happens to fall in line with the weekly pre-aggregated data from the CTE. Be wary of that if you shift bounds.

Finally, `to_char(t.wk, 'YYYY"-W"IW')` is a compact expression to get your desired format for week numbers. Details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: This seems Perfect . Many thanks for this wonderful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the date_part() function with a group by like this:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_PART('year', created_at)::varchar || '-W' || DATE_PART('week', created_at)::varchar,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'opened' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: This is not the answer i expected.here you simply group the count of email which have OPEN status group by weeks.I want for each week the count of previous 90 days.But thanks a lot for the answer.